# Accessing runtime created annotations on Titanium MapView

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm very new to Titanium so this might be a stupid question, anyway I can't solve this issue:

I have a mapview created on the .xml like this:

```
<View id="mapview" ns="Ti.Map" mapType="Ti.Map.STANDARD_TYPE" >
    <Annotation id="place" latitude="20.735145" longitude="-103.4548" title="Tech" pincolor="Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED" leftButton="/images/appcelerator_small.png" />
</View>
```

On the .js, at runtime I create and add new annotations to the mapview like this:

```
var newDropMessage = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
        latitude:10,
        longitude:10,
        title:"Hi",
        pincolor:Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,           
        animate:true,
        rightButton: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DISCLOSURE
    });

    $.mapview.addAnnotation(newDropMessage); //Add the annotation
```

Later on the code I cant cycle trough each of the annotations, and only the first annotation (the one created at the XML) shows the alert with a code like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < $.mapview.annotations.length; i++)
{
    alert($.mapview.annotations[i].title);
}
```

I created many more annotations but only one appear. How can I show all annotations?

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatched the wrong annotation object with the wrong map.

There are two types of `MapViews` in Titanium for Android, [the add-on native module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map), and the old [Titanium.Map](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Map) API. You are using the add on module. Note this in the docs:

> This module is a replacement for the built-in Titanium.Map module on Android, which uses the Google Maps API v1. The Google Maps API v1 is deprecated and Google will no longer issue new Maps API v1 keys after March 3rd, 2013. New applications should use this module on Android

In your code you are creating the wrong annotation type, from the *old* MapView. Instead create your annotations like this using the new module:

```
// Include the new map module
var NewMapModule = require('ti.map');
var mountainView = NewMapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude:37.390749,
    longitude:-122.081651,
    title:"Appcelerator Headquarters",
    subtitle:'Mountain View, CA',
    pincolor:Alloy.Globals.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
    myid:1 // Custom property to uniquely identify this annotation.
});

$.mapview.region = {latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993,
                    latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01};
$.mapview.addAnnotation(mountainView);
```

This is why you only see the one annotation, because it was instantiated correctly by Alloy.